# Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

While running this code i got an error that "cannot read property extend of undefined"

```
 App.Produt=DS.Model.extend({
    name:DS.attr(),
    description:DS.attr(),
    price:DS.attr()
 });
 App.Store=DS.Store.extend({

adapter:'DS.FixtureAdapter' 
});

 App.ProductAdapter=DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
 App.Product.FIXTURES=[
    {
        id:1,
        name:'playstation 3',
        description:'something',
        price:200
    }
 ];
```

Comment: Have u created var App = Ember.Application.create(); and also included ember data

Comment: yes,i created it and also add emberdata,,but it shows the above error

Comment: Which line is giving the undefined error? Can you reproduce ur error in emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Is there a reason you have chosen to use the "globals" style of development (see how everything is prefixed with `App.`) instead of Ember-CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what ember-data version you are using, this might be due to the FixtureAdapter. The FixtureAdapter is not part of the current ember-data versions anymore.
If it is a newer ember-version (released since May 15) you can have a look at [this project](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-data-fixture-adapter)

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,  using **Ember 1.6.0** this is how I fixed it.

1. Find the location right after `App = Ember.Application.create();`
2. Extend the DS.FixtureAdapter:  `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();`

That should work.

**Otherwise**

include `import DS from 'ember-data'` at the top of your *app.js* file